# How to separate individual actions into separate functions

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in PHP & Symfony. I've created same action who work. 
Now I've not knowd how to separate individual actions into separate functions. 
Run on Symfony 3 / PHP 7.1.

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Controller/SuccessMYController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use AppBundle\Entity\SuccessMY;
use AppBundle\Form\SuccessMYType;

/**
 * @Route("/success")
 *
 */
class SuccessMYController extends Controller
{
   /**
     *
     * @Route("/new/{idTask}",
     *     name = "MY_success_new")
     */
    public function newSuccessAction( Request $request, $idTask )
    {
        if ( !$this -> get( 'security.authorization_checker' ) -> isGranted( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' ) ) {
            throw $this -> createAccessDeniedException();
        }
        $user1 = $this -> get( 'security.token_storage' ) -> getToken() -> getUser() -> getId();


        // (1) load TASK data for a new Success
        $em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getRepository( 'EinsteMYBundle:TaskMY' );
        $taskData = $em
            -> findOneBy( [ 'id' => $idTask ] );


        // (2) create fefault data
        $newSuccess = new SuccessMY();
        $newSuccess
            -> setUserID( $user1 )
            -> setEndTask( false );


        // (3) display form
        $form = $this -> createForm( SuccessMYType::class, $newSuccess );
        $form -> handleRequest( $request ) -> getData( $newSuccess );


        // **********************************************
        // (4) save after submit
        if ( $form -> isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {

            // (4.5.1) The content of the confirmation message
            $messageFrom = $this -> get( 'translator' ) -> trans( 'success.created' );

            // Data update newSuccess
            // (4.5.2) Date assignment
            $successNewDate = new \DateTime();
            $newSuccess
                -> setDateSuccess( $successNewDate );
            $successNewDate = $newSuccess -> getDateSuccess() -> format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );


            // (4.6.1)  Increase the number
            $taskData
                -> setOwnCount( $taskData -> getOwnCount() + 1 );

            // (4.6.3)  TASK Setting status
            if ( $newSuccess -> getEndTask() == true ) {
                $taskData
                    -> setStatusTask( 8 );
                $messageTask = $this -> get( 'translator' ) -> trans( 'task.status.succeed' );
                $messageFrom = $messageFrom . ' ' . $messageTask;
            }


            // **** (4.8) Activities in the database *****
            // (4.8.1) Save newly created database success
            $em2 = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();
            $em2 -> persist( $newSuccess );
            $em2 -> flush();

            // (4.8.2) Query updating overrides Task with newSuccess
            $sql
                = "UPDATE task_MY t
                    INNER JOIN zz_tech_parent e
                        on t.id = e.idParent
                    SET
                        t.success_count = t.success_count + 1
                    WHERE
                        e.idTask =  :parTaskId";
            $params = [
                'parTaskId'      => $idTask,
            ];

            $em4 = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();
            $phrase = $em4 -> getConnection() -> prepare( $sql );
            $phrase -> execute( $params );


            // (4.9) Return to task list
            // And a message about the success of the operation
            $this -> get( 'session' ) -> getFlashBag() -> add( 'msg', $messageFrom );

            return
                $this -> redirect( $this -> generateUrl( 'MY_tasks_all' ) );
        }

        // (5) For bad data return to form
        return $this -> render( 'EinsteMYBundle:SuccessMY:newSuccess.html.twig',
                                [
                                    'form'     => $form -> createView(),
                                    'taskData' => $taskData,
                                ]
        );
    }

    // (...)
}
```

Where can I find examples of how to send code to similar functions?
Which activities should (preferably) be separated so that coding is as transparent as possible when adding new activities?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: 1: `$em`is actually the TaskMYRepository. 2: default values can be set in the entity (or in the db through entity config/annotations) 4.5.1: you can do the translations in twig. 4.5.2: same as 2. Note that the last assignment ($successNewDate  = $newS...) is never used. 4.6.1/4.6.3 unclear what these are. $em2 and $em4 is the same, don't have to fetch the em twice. 4.8.2: sql (dql)  should be in a repository. Some parts of this (adding the current user to new SuccessMY, changing task status etc) seem to fit in an event driven design (having a listener on changes and doing that logic there)

Comment: You don't need this part from the form handling `-> getData( $newSuccess )`. I realize this ended up more of a "clean up" than modularization. but it's at least somewhere to start

Comment: @JimL thanks for advice. How set default values for userID, I've read in function?

Comment: EndTask can be set to false by default, the current user id can be set in an event listener

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas:

1) Move your form handling stuff to a separate method under your `Controller`. Pass in your entity (`SuccessMY`) and the `Request` objects as the arguments and return your `$form->createView()`

```
...

public function processForm(SuccessMY $successMy, request $request){

    $form = $this -> createForm( SuccessMYType::class, $newSuccess );
    $form -> handleRequest( $request ) -> getData( $newSuccess );

    ...

    return $form->createView();

}

...
```

2) Typehint your `$idTask` and rename it to `$task` - it will make Symfony to load that entity for you if it exists.

```
 public function newSuccessAction( Request $request, !YOUR_TASK_TYPE! $task )
```

3) This kind of stuff clearly belongs to a Repository:

```
   $sql
            = "UPDATE task_MY t
                INNER JOIN zz_tech_parent e
                    on t.id = e.idParent
                SET
                    t.success_count = t.success_count + 1
                WHERE
                    e.idTask =  :parTaskId";
        $params = [
            'parTaskId'      => $idTask,
        ];
```

Something like:

```
class GroupRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    public function incrementSuccessCounterByTask(YOUR_TASK_TYPE $task){
       ....
    }
}
```

4) You don't really need to have multiple entity managers within the same scope. So better have a single $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() at the beginning of your Action and then just use it as needed. Get rid of those $em1, $em2 etc.

Also - this spot 
`$em = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getRepository( 'EinsteMYBundle:TaskMY' );`

It really creates a Repository instance, not an EntityManager so you should rename the variable to something like `$taskMyRepository = ...`

Comment: Thanks @StasParshin. for response. I move SQL code to `Repository`. I do not sure what put to  processForm function - The code  `if ( $form -> isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )` mast be outside or include?

Comment: Yes, you should get the validation check into that method too. There is also some space for improvement with your $em usage - will add few tips to my answer